# Rails loop showing duplicate results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models with the following associations:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store
  has_many :variants, dependent: :destroy
end

class Store < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :variants
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
end

class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :store, optional: true
end
```

And I'm counting the products & variants of each user with the following:

```
@products = current_user.store.products.group(:subcategory_id).count
@variants = current_user.store.variants.group(:subcategory_id).count
```

The above returns this `@products` `=> {181=>1, 185=>1}`
and this `@variants` `=> {181=>2, 185=>1}`

Finally when I try to loop through each of the above hashes the results show up correctly but they also show up two times(dublicate results). Any ideas on how to fix this??

```
<% @products.each do |product_key, product_value| %>
  <% @variants.each do |variant_key, variant_value| %>
    <%= @child_category.name %> - <%= @subcategory.name %><br>
    Products: <%= product_value %><br>
    Variants: <%= variant_value %><br>
    Total Products: <%= product_value + variant_value %><br>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach output page here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rishi Pithadiya... I just added a snapshot of what I'm getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not duplicating anything, this is expected behavior. It shows each product with its variants.

You're looping through two hashes, which contains 2 pairs, so the outer loop executes 2 times and the inner loop executes `2 * 2 => 4` times.

This is the expected behavior.

And if you wanted to show only a single pair, you can add if condition over there for subcategory -

i.e. I wanted to show only results where subcategory is Boys then you can use following code -

```
<% @products.each do |product_key, product_value| %>
  <% @variants.each do |variant_key, variant_value| %>
    <% if @subcategory.name == 'Boys' %>
      <%= @child_category.name %> - <%= @subcategory.name %><be>
      Products: <%= product_value %><be>
      Variants: <%= variant_value %><be>
      Total Products: <%= product_value + variant_value %><be>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hmmm... so how can I show only 1 pair instead of 2 pairs?